# Youtube API v3, youtube.videos.list returns forbidden for suggestions?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-api, youtube-javascript-api

Okay so heres the call I'm trying to make:

[image: Api call]

and here's the error it gives me:

[image: youtube api error]

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?
Whats the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `suggestions` part returns automated suggestions about tags that a video owner might want to attach to a video, or video editing suggestions concerning how a video owner might make modifications for playback purposes. They're designed to be used for apps building their own upload system ... the returned info is thus considered private info and is only accessible via oAuth2 calls for those videos owned by the authorized user.

More detailed info here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#suggestions

Comment: Thanks, now I understand I should use search with `relatedToId' attribute set.